# Запрос в базу AND  ?OR

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM [BASE].[dbo].[text] WHERE [textsub] = 'text' AND [from] = 0 AND [from] = 1
```

Мне нужно выбрать и `from 0` и `from 1`. Делаю через OR - не получается. Что не так?

Может, через вложения сделать запрос?

Comment: Есть оператор in.

Answer (score 1):

За mssql не скажу, но, думаю, как и в любой СУБД должен работать приоритет логических операторов в виде скобок.

```
SELECT ... WHERE (... OR ...) AND ...
```